# Angular 6 ngIf not working with ngrx store reducers models

Tags: redux, angular6, store, ngrx, reducers

I am a newbie at redux and I have been reading and working on this for the past couple of days, but I keep coming to a point where there are zero errors and zero warnings, yet the expected behavior is not being achieved.

Basically, I have a login, which contacts the local MySQL and returns a json object, from there, I would like a dropdown menu to appear. If they are an admin, then they should see more options in the dropdown menu.

Once again, zero errors and zero warnings. I do not know what I am missing.

The following is my user.state.ts file:

```
import { User } from "./models/user.models";

export interface UserState {
  readonly user: User[];
}
```

The following is my user.models.ts file:

```
  export interface User {
  uName: string;
  isAdmin: number;
  ts: string;
  loggedIn: boolean;
}
```

The following is my user.actions.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";
import { User } from "../models/user.models";

export const LOGGEDIN_USER = "[USER] LoggedIn";
export const LOGGEDOUT_USER = "[USER] LoggedOut";

export class LoggedInUser implements Action {
  readonly type = LOGGEDIN_USER;

  constructor(public payload: User) {}
}

export class LoggedOutUser implements Action {
  readonly type = LOGGEDOUT_USER;

  constructor(public payload: User) {}
}

export type Actions = LoggedInUser | LoggedOutUser;
```

The following is my reducer file:

```
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";
import { User } from "../models/user.models";
import * as UserActions from "../actions/user.actions";

const initialState: User = {
  uName: "Guest",
  isAdmin: 0,
  ts: "2018-12-27 00:00:00",
  loggedIn: false
};

export function reducer(
  state: User[] = [initialState],
  action: UserActions.Actions
) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case UserActions.LOGGEDIN_USER:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case UserActions.LOGGEDOUT_USER:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Now when my services receives JSON from the API, I call a methond, which dispatches to store:

```
addUser(uName, isAdmin, ts, loggedIn) {
this.store.dispatch(
  new UserActions.LoggedInUser({
    uName: uName,
    isAdmin: isAdmin,
    ts: ts,
    loggedIn: true
  })
);
}
```

In my navbar component, I have the following:

```
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { User } from "../models/user.models";
import { UserState } from "../user.state";
```

Within the class:

```
  users: Observable<User[]>;
constructor(private store: Store<UserState>) {
  this.users = store.select("user");
}
```

In my navbar, I have a dropdown menu that I would like to appear, once this model has loggedIn set to true:

```
<li *ngIf="users.loggedIn" ngbDropdown class="nav-item dropdown">
```

I have also tried user.loggedIn, UserActions.LoggedInUser.loggedIn, etc...

And nothing happens. The dropdown menu is not visible at the beginning and I thought this is great, but nothing changes after login. After I have this part working, then I will apply the same logic to the login and register buttons in the navbar, except I will use !users.loggedIn.

Thanks in advance - sorry for any typos or grammar errors, but I am tired. I have been at this for a couple of days.

Comment: Does your state look as expected? You can investigate your state with the redux devtools. https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools

Comment: @timdeschryver thanks for the response and thanks for the link to devtools. I will use them from now on. I was able to check my state and it was working as expected. I am about to post my solution

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is going through this, the following is my solution and I have a question at the end of my solution.

The following is my 'reducers/index.ts' file:

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from "@ngrx/store";
import { reducer, User } from "./user.reducer";

interface AppState {
  appReducer: User;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  appReducer: reducer
};
```

Which also imports my 'reducers/user.reducer.ts' file:

```
import * as UserActions from "../actions/user.actions";
/* use mTstamp function to calculate timestamp within typescript */
function mTstamp() {
  let d = new Date();
  let mMonth;
  if (d.getMonth() < 10) {
    mMonth = "0" + d.getMonth();
  } else {
    mMonth = d.getMonth();
  }
  let mDate;
  if (d.getDate() < 10) {
    mDate = "0" + d.getDate();
  } else {
    mDate = d.getDate();
  }
  let mHours;
  if (d.getHours() < 10) {
    mHours = "0" + d.getHours();
  } else {
    mHours = d.getHours();
  }
  let mMins;
  if (d.getMinutes() < 10) {
    mMins = "0" + d.getMinutes();
  } else {
    mMins = d.getMinutes();
  }
  let mSecs;
  if (d.getSeconds() < 10) {
    mSecs = "0" + d.getSeconds();
  } else {
    mSecs = d.getSeconds();
  }
  let mTimeStamp =
    d.getFullYear() +
    "-" +
    mMonth +
    "-" +
    mDate +
    " " +
    mHours +
    ":" +
    mMins +
    ":" +
    mSecs;
  console.log("mTimeStamp: ", mTimeStamp);
  return mTimeStamp;
}

export interface User {
  uName: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
  ts: string;
  loggedIn: boolean;
}

const initialState: User = {
  uName: "Guest",
  isAdmin: false,
  ts: mTstamp(),
  loggedIn: false
};

export function reducer(appUserState = initialState, action): User {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UserActions.ACTION_LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...appUserState,
        uName: "Guest",
        isAdmin: false,
        ts: mTstamp(),
        loggedIn: false
      };
    case UserActions.ACTION_LOGIN:
      return {
        ...appUserState,
        uName: action.payload,
        isAdmin: action.payload,
        ts: action.payload,
        loggedIn: action.payload
      };
  }
  return appUserState;
}
```

The index.ts file also imports the 'actions/user.actions.ts' file:

```
export const ACTION_LOGIN = "LoggedIn";
export const ACTION_LOGOUT = "LoggedOut";
```

That is all that I need to make a redux for logging in and out.

Within the components, most of my logic ran through the services file, which handles logging in via the db:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { User } from "./reducers/user.reducer";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import * as UserActions from "./actions/user.actions";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ShoppingCartValuesService {
  public shoppingCartValues = "n";
  public loginObj: any;
  public uri = "<path to some local php api>";
  user: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private store: Store<any>
  ) {}

  getLogin(email, password) {
    return new Observable(observe => {
      this.http
        .get(this.uri + "?name=" + email + "&pass1=" + password)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.loginObj = res;
          if (this.loginObj.uName != null || this.loginObj.uName !== "Guest") {
            this.loginObj.loggedIn = true;
            this.getState();
            this.updateState({
              action: UserActions.ACTION_LOGIN,
              payload: this.loginObj
            });
          }
          observe.next(res);
          this.router.navigate(["/"]);
        });
    });
  }

  getState() {
    return this.store.select("appReducer");
  }

  updateState(obj) {
    this.store.dispatch({
      type: obj.action,
      payload: obj.payload
    });
    console.log("this.loginObj from updateState: ", this.loginObj);
  }

  logout() {
    const logoutObj = {
      action: UserActions.ACTION_LOGOUT,
      payload: {
        uName: "Guest",
        isAdmin: 0,
        ts: "2018-12-28 00:00:00",
        loggedIn: false
      }
    };
    this.store.dispatch({
      type: logoutObj.action,
      payload: logoutObj.payload
    });
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
  }
}
```

As you can see, when the result (res) is returned, I check if a username is in the JSON object, which means php found a match. From there, getState(), which selects the store "appReducer" and updateState() dispatches the changes to the store.

The following is the relevant portion of the navbar, to what I was trying to accomplish and it leads to a question that I have, but I will place it at the end:

```
  <li *ngIf="!appUserState.loggedIn" class="nav-item">
    <a
      class="nav-link"
      data-toggle="tooltip"
      title="Register"
      id="register"
      routerLink="/register"
      ><span>Register</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="!appUserState.loggedIn" class="nav-item">
    <a
      class="nav-link"
      data-toggle="tooltip"
      title="Login"
      routerLink="/login"
      id="login-btn"
      ><span>Login</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li *ngIf="appUserState.loggedIn" ngbDropdown class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a
      ngbDropdownToggle
      class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
      href="//:javascript"
      id="dropdown01"
      data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded="false"
      >More</a
    >
    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
      <a
        class="dropdown-item"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        title="My orders"
        routerLink="/my-orders"
        id="search-records"
        ><span>Search Records</span></a
      >
      <a
        *ngIf="appUserState.isAdmin.isAdmin != '0'"
        class="dropdown-item"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        title="Admin search records"
        routerLink="/admin/orders"
        id="admin-search-records"
        ><span>Admin Search Records</span></a
      >
      <a
        *ngIf="appUserState.isAdmin.isAdmin != '0'"
        class="dropdown-item"
        data-toggle="tooltip"
        title="Admin products"
        routerLink="/admin/products"
        id="admin-products"
        ><span>Admin Products</span></a
      >
```

The following is the relevant portion of the app.module.ts file:

```
import { StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { reducers } from "./reducers/";
```

Later down in the imports array:

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {}),
```

Now, this works 100%, along with zero errors or warnings. However, as you may have noticed, I had to apply a somewhat of a hack in the navbar - *ngIf="appUserState.isAdmin.isAdmin != '0'"

Why would the system see appUserState as an object within an object? In other words, why did it not recognize *ngIf="appUserState.isAdmin != '0'" - it wasn't until that I saw that appUserState.isAdmin was what I thought appUserState was, that I realized it would allows evaluate to true, because the object existed. When I used the console to open the object and found an object within, which had the property of isAdmin, that is when I solved the issue by adding on another .isAdmin

If someone could explain that one to me, then that would be a cherry on top of the icing.  Otherwise, it is working and that is good enough for now.

Thanks in advance